# Building a dynamic page on lift/scala

Tags: scala, lift

I want to build a dynamic web page with Lift/Scala. I'd like the server to push events to the client, and every event should display a new component on the web page.

How can that be achieved?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To "push" events from the server to the client, you can use Lift's comet support:
http://www.assembla.com/spaces/liftweb/wiki/Comet_Support